# Azure - The request could not be completed. (Internal Server Error)

Tags: azure, xamarin

[image]I'm using Xamarin.Forms with azure and everything been working fine, but today I started getting this weird error - "The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)", the only thing that I know of that I've changed lately is the sql server password. So I'm wondering if that could be the issue of if it could be something else and how to fix it. The diagnostics tool is also showing http server errors whenever a request is attempted.

Comment: Check your server logs

Comment: @Cheesebaron where would I find it

Comment: @Cheesebaron I just checked for issues on the server and it detected http server errors

Comment: Dunno, you haven't barely described your environment. Saying that you are using Azure, doesn't tell much, it could be any of the many services. Usually the Azure Portal could reveal it or the logging service you use.

Comment: Is it a VM, Web App, IIS, Apache,....?

Comment: @Liam xamarin. Forms web app

Comment: @AppleGeek Oh yeah, duh. Silly me! Azure has a lot of logging features within the web management application so it's definitely worth checking those.

Comment: @Liam yeah i did it said its an http server error

Comment: Have you enabled the option for detailed error messages? It should say more than a standard http server error.

Comment: @Liam I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So, a stupid question, but you mention that you've recently changed the SQL Server Password.  Did you in fact also update the website config with the new password?

Comment: @BrendanGreen what do you mean by updating the website config?

Comment: Did you update the SQL server connection in the web apps code?

Comment: @JamesDonovan Do you mean the connection key

Comment: @AppleGeek do you have sql related connection string in your app?

Comment: @AppleGeek can you please show a screenshot (with necessary sensitive information blacked out) of exactly where in Azure your "web app" is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out, sure enough it was the change in my sql server password, to fix it I simply changed it back to what it originally was.